# Java string spilt not working

Tags: java, regex

My String as given below

```
     PID USER      PR  NI  VIRT  RES  SHR S  %CPU %MEM    TIME+  COMMAND
    1 root      20   0 24416 2408 1360 S   0.0  0.2   0:00.88 init
   10 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kdevtmpfs
  171 root       0 -20     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 mpt_poll_0
  818 messageb  20   0 23940 1260  920 S   0.0  0.1   0:00.97 dbus-daemon
  995 whoopsie  20   0  185m 4224 3000 S   0.0  0.4   0:00.06 whoopsie
 1000 daemon    20   0 16908  156    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.19 atd
24043 root      20   0  570m 3952 2780 S   0.0  0.4   0:04.28 console-kit-dae
24110 root      20   0  182m 3032 2484 S   0.0  0.3   0:01.66 polkitd
26310 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 flush-8:0
30081 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.02 kworker/0:1
31381 root      20   0     0    0    0 S   0.0  0.0   0:00.00 kworker/0:2
31511 root      20   0 81900 3904 3048 S   0.0  0.4   0:00.03 sshd
31646 root      20   0 19228 1376 1060 R   0.0  0.1   0:00.00 top
```

now I want splits this string so I used following java function

```
for(int i = 0; i < mystring.length; i++){
    String[] values = mystring.split("\\s+");
    System.out.println(values[0]);
}
```

but when I check `values[0]` it shows only 31646 not display other? I think it wrong with my regular expression in split so I also tried this `"\\t\\n\\x0B\\f\\r"` but it not work. If any one knows how to manged this?

Comment: Why is it in a loop? What is the point of `i`?

Comment: What output are you expecting?! Based on what do you want to split your String?

Comment: `mystring.trim().split("\\s+");` so the preceding spaces cause no empty string at `[0]`.

Comment: can you please tell me what do you want as output. do you want the output as the whole first column of PID?

Comment: Your code is terribly wrong. It won't even compile. Fix it.

Comment: Hi I want output like in json string like [{pid:1,user:root,PR:20},...{pid:31646,user:root,PR:20}]

Comment: change `System.out.println(values[0]);` to `System.out.println(values[i]);`, note how I changed `values[0]` to `values[i]`.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what output you want, but try this code instead.

```
String[] values = mystring.split("\\s+");
for(int i=0; i<values.length;i++)
{
    System.out.println(values[i]);
}
```

This will split and display everything separated in a space in mystring.

Edit: Now that I know what you want, I can help you a little more. What you want is a 2d array so you can have it the way you want it. If you do this:

```
String[] values = mystring.split("\\s+");
String[][12] output;
for(int i = 0; i < (values.length)/12 ;i++)
{
    for(int i = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
        output[i][j] = values[i*12 + j];
    }
}
```

Since there are 12 commands, the array will be an x by 12. Now you can print them in another loop.

```
for(int i = 0; i < output.length; i++)
{
    for(int j = 0; j < 12; j++)
    {
        System.out.print(output[i][j] + " ");
    }
    System.out.println(" ");
}
```

You can also just create a class and store each value as a variable. What you want to do just is more fit for an array of objects.

Comment: "I don't know what output you want" - then how can you come up with a proposed solution?

Comment: @tbsalling Dom probably guessed it from the question.  This looks more usefull, but it still is impossible to tell if it is what the OP actually wants.

Answer (score 0):

Well I believe \s should be sufficient enough to do the job. I would suggest you remove the plus. Try this.

```
String[] values = mystring.split("\\s+");

for(int i=0; i<mystring.length;i++){
    System.out.println(values[0]);
}
```

you kept the array in the for clause which is wrong. This should work.
If you have questions, pls ask. And mark as answer if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to print the first element I have tried below code and it worked perfectly fine

String mystring = "1111    2222   eeeeeee  www          eeeeee";

```
        String[] values = mystring.split("\\s+");
        for(int i=0; i< values.length;i++){
        System.out.println(values[i]);
        }
```